# How NOT to use all arguments when using capture operator?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to understand capture operator and where it can be used. Here is working example:

```
%{name: "Daniel", dob: 2016, email: "daniel@gmail.com"}
|> Enum.filter(fn({_k, v}) -> is_binary(v) end)
|> Enum.into(%{})
```

which returns

> %{email: "daniel@gmail.com", name: "Daniel"} .

Now I'm trying to use capture operator inside Enum.filter/2 where I'm using the second element from map pair.

```
%{name: "Daniel", dob: 2016, email: "daniel@gmail.com"}
|> Enum.filter(&is_binary(&2))
|> Enum.into(%{})
```

and the iex console says

```
** (CompileError) iex:2: capture &2 cannot be defined without &1
    (elixir) src/elixir_fn.erl:118: :elixir_fn.do_capture/4
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.|>/2
             iex:2: (file)
```

The result is somewhat expected. My question is how to bypass this, how can I use second element as argument without using the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error message says, you cannot use just the second argument using the capture operator, BUT, the function `fn({_k, v}) -> is_binary(v) end` only takes one argument, which is a 2 element tuple, not 2 arguments. You can use `elem/2` if you don't want to name it:

```
iex(1)> %{name: "Daniel", dob: 2016, email: "daniel@gmail.com"} |>
...(1)> Enum.filter(&is_binary(elem(&1, 1))) |>
...(1)> Enum.into(%{})
%{email: "daniel@gmail.com", name: "Daniel"}
```

For this particular use case, you can also use `:maps.filter/2`. It's shorter than your original code and likely more efficient:

```
iex(2)> :maps.filter fn k, v -> is_binary(v) end, %{name: "Daniel", dob: 2016, email: "daniel@gmail.com"}
%{email: "daniel@gmail.com", name: "Daniel"}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So the fn {key, val} is deconstructing the pairs from the initial map in two parts, on key and val, and after that I can choose what I want to do with them - key and val - individually inside that anonymous function?

Comment: Yes, in your original code the function gets only 1 argument, which is a tuple containing the key and value, and due to pattern matching, `_k` gets the key and `v` gets the value.